# error“ org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/” with GeckoDriver and Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Hello  i can't test my junit  this my error when i try to compile if someone can help me thank you

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:18218
>   Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
>   System info: host: 'UTILISA-3AHNTLM', ip: '10.2.10.137', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Here is code for your reference: Note : It works fine on mac when i build with Junit

```
package ca.qc.grasset_420_pa4_ag.lab05.authentification;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import ca.qc.grasset._420_pa4_ag.lab05.commons.AbstractFunctionalTest;

public final class InvalidUsernameLoginTest

    extends AbstractFunctionalTest {

    public InvalidUsernameLoginTest() {

        super();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        getDriver().get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        getDriver().findElement(By.linkText("Form Authentication"))
            .click();
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("username"))
            .click();
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("username"))
            .clear();
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("username"))
            .sendKeys("fdjkfgjkgfhkgf");
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("password"))
            .click();
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("password"))
            .clear();
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("password"))
            .sendKeys("SuperSecretPassword!");
        getDriver().findElement(
            By.xpath(
                "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Password'])[1]/following::button[1]"))
            .click();
        validate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void validate() {

        WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"flash\"]"));

        String actualMessage = element.getText();
        Assert.assertTrue("Your username is invalid!\n×".equals(actualMessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: You said it works fine on the mac. And where are you getting this error?

Comment: error in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:18218
```

...implies that the **ConnectException** was raised while initializing the *WebDriver* session.

---

### Solution

Some more information regarding the binaries you are using might have been helpful to debug this issue which are as follows:

- Your *GeckoDriver* version.
- Your *Firefox* version.

Some of the potential solutions to your issue are:

- Ensure that `/etc/hosts` on your system contains the following entry:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
  #or
  127.0.0.1 localhost loopback
  ```
- Ensure the GeckoDriver-Firefox Mapping

[image: Geckodriver Releases]

- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.23.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is present in the specified location.
- Ensure *GeckoDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v62.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.

Comment: Hi in the host file i found only 127.0.0.1 localhost i have to replace it to 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost ? sorry im beginner

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of Wojciech-Kopec](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/408) helps me solve this issue, that maybe u not install  ***Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable*** yet

Try to download and install the appropriate .exe file [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Hope this helps!